# variable assignment and IFS

Tags: linux, bash

[Per Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) the `IFS` variable is used:

- In the `read` command, if multiple variable-name arguments are
  specified, `IFS` is used to split the line of input so that each
  variable gets a single field of the input.
- When performing WordSplitting on an unquoted expansion, `IFS` is used
  to split the value of the expansion into multiple words.
- When performing the `"$*"` or `"${array[*]}"` expansion,the first character of `IFS` is placed between the elements in order to construct the final output string.
- When doing `"${!prefix*}"`, the first character of `IFS` is placed
  between the variable names to make the output string.
- `IFS` is used by `complete -W` under programmable completion

So my question is, why should `IFS` have to come into play in variable assignment? Per the below, bash is applying word-splitting on the string on the right(`a:b:c:d`).

```
$ IFS=: s=a:b:c:d
$ echo $s
a b c d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't. You need to [quote properly](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). Word splitting is applied to unquoted expansions according to the value of IFS. The problem is your `echo` command, not the assignment.

```
 $ ( IFS=: s=a:b:c:d typeset -p s )
declare -- s="a:b:c:d"
```